# How does partitioning and the lack of a primary key affect ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE

Tags: mysql, partitioning, update

Consider a table with the following columns:

```
phone BIGINT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
name VARCHAR(64),
state VARCHAR(64)
```

We would like to partition the table on `state`, however that would require dropping the primary key constraint on `phone` and replacing that constraint with a `UNIQUE` constraint. We make use of `INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` and I would like to know how it would affect the system. Surprisingly little is written on the subject from reliable sources, and I'm sure that there are hidden gotchas which will not be immediately apparent to my naive eye.

**What problems might we encounter with a partitioned table lacking a primary key, especially in regards to `INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` queries?**

The database in question in running MySQL 5.5 on Amazon RDS. The table in question has upward of 20 million rows and is often used in JOINs with other similarly-sized tables.

Comment: What do you mean you have to drop the primary key? Show us the table definitions, both now and the planned with the partition.

Answer (score -1):

When we talk about partitioning tables in relational database platforms is recommended that it is always done on tables where the field is numeric. As a suggestion I would create an additional field that would serve as a surrogate key and this in turn would be used for partitioning the table.

Comment: Really? Never partition on `date` columns?

Comment: Could you please substantiate that claim? I've never heard it and I do not see why it would be valid.

Comment: Why was this downvoted? Could the downvoter elaborate, or provide another viewpoint?